# Angular dynamic form binding

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm new to **Angular**, and I actually want to ask if there's a clean way to implement this behaviour:

Let's say I have a dynamic form that I want to bind into a model, for example, this form would let you create a bookshelf.
A **bookshelf** have got a name and a list of **books**, then every **book** have got a **name** and **author**.
Let's say it's going to be a form to define a book, and with an "**Add Book**" button shows you a form to define a new **book** (you can add as much **books** as you want).

The result I want to reach is a JSON like : `{name : "shelf1", books : [//json objects of books]}`
Is there a way to implement this behaviour properly using Angular? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many ways in angular to solve this problem. Being new to angular, I suggest brushing up on some of the terms (e.g. directive if that is unfamiliar). The first solution I thought of (and it tends to follow the problem domain closely) is to make a directive for both bookShelf and book. The book is contained within a bookshelf. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjf9D/).

```
//define a module
var mod = angular.module("myApp", []);

//Main Controller
mod.controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {
    //empty shelves
    $scope.shelves = [];

    $scope.addShelf = function () {
        //make a new shelf
        $scope.shelves.push({name: "", books: []});
    }
});

//define a bookShelf directive
mod.directive("bookShelf", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {bookShelf: '='},
        template: 'Shelf Name: <input ng-model="bookShelf.name"><br><div ng-repeat="bk in bookShelf.books"><div class="book" book="bk"></div></div><button ng-click="addBook()">Add Book</button>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.addBook = function () {
                $scope.bookShelf.books.push({name: "", author: ""});
            }
        }
    }
});

//define a book directive
mod.directive("book", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {book: '='},
        //Only requiring bookshelf here because a book is likely to be useless if not on a shelf.
        require: "^bookShelf",
        template: 'Book Name: <input ng-model = "book.name"><br>Author: <input ng-model="book.author">',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //Not doing anything here yet
        }
    }
});
```

And sample HTML to use it:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="shelf in shelves">
        <div class="shelf" book-shelf="shelf"></div>
        Shelf JSON: {{shelf}}
        <br><br>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <button ng-click="addShelf()">Add Shelf</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very well possible whatever you said in your question. To implement this you must have to use **ng-repeat** directive of *angularjs*.

Here is the example:

This is the div which will repeat your controls.

```
<div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="book in books">
  <label for="book" ng-show="showBookLabel(book)">Books</label>
  <button ng-show="showAddBook(book)" ng-click="addNewBook()">Add another book</button>
  <input type="text" ng-model="book.name" name="" placeholder="Enter a book name">
</div>
```

Dynamic insertion of controls happens because of this line of code:

```
data-ng-repeat="choice in choices"
```

ng-repeat repeat each and every time with  from controller's declaration like this:

```
$scope.books = [{id: 'book1'}, {id: 'book2'}, {id: 'book3'}];
```

And at last this is the click event which will trigger and defined as:

```
$scope.addNewBook = function() {
  var newItemNo = $scope.books.length+1;
  $scope.books.push({'id':'book'+newItemNo});
};
```

For more details about [ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) you can see [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)